# Mathematical Model for SiC MOSFET C2M0080120D, transconductance and capacities

Tags: mosfet, modeling, transconductance

I am currently trying to use the model described in the paper "An Improved Analytical Model for Predicting the Switching Performance of SiC MOSFETs" in MathLab to simulate/imitate it. The paper can be downloaded for free. I use the parameters presented in the paper. A more recent paper that describe such a model in such detail is unfortunately not known to me. Unfortunately, I don't get any good results yet. In my opinion I don’t understand some things correctly. My questions:

- In many data sheets of SiC-MOSFETs, parameters such as the transconductance g<sub>fs</sub> are given under certain conditions. I use the data sheet C2M0080120D Rev. C, 10-2015, since this SiC-MOSFET was used in the paper to evaluate the model. In this datasheet, g<sub>fs</sub> is given at I<sub>ds</sub> = 20 A. Other parameters such as the gate threshold voltage are given at a specific current I<sub>d</sub>. My question is: What is the difference between I<sub>d</sub> and I<sub>ds</sub>. Aren’t they both the drain-source-current or does I<sub>d</sub> correspond to the channel current I<sub>ch</sub>?
- I don't understand how I can get g<sub>fs</sub> from the datasheet. According to the paper and to my knowledge g<sub>fs</sub> is defined by: I<sub>ch</sub> = g<sub>fs</sub>(v<sub>gs</sub> - V<sub>th</sub>). If I<sub>d</sub> = I<sub>ch</sub>, I should be able to determine g<sub>fs</sub> from fig. 7 of the datasheet.  Let's take g<sub>fs</sub> = 8.1 S, which is given in the datasheet for V<sub>ds</sub> = 20 V and I<sub>ds</sub> = 20 A. I suppose the junction temperature is T<sub>j</sub> = 25 °C. If I try to determine g<sub>fs</sub> = 8.1 S, I would get g<sub>fs</sub> = I<sub>ch</sub>/(v<sub>gs</sub> - V<sub>th</sub>) = 20 A/(11 V - 2.5 V) = 2.35 S and not 8.1 S:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

- In the paper the author presents the characteristic curve (fig. 5) from where you can determine g<sub>fs</sub> with I<sub>ch</sub>(v<sub>gs</sub>). Let's compare his characteristic curve with the one from the data sheet, it does not match. Does anyone have any idea how the author came up with this data/curve?

[image]

- I am also confused by the specifications on the parasitic capacities in the data sheet. Ciss, Coss and Crss are given with 950pF, 80pF and 7.6pF at V<sub>ds</sub> = 1000 V respectively. I can confirm C<sub>oss</sub> and C<sub>rss</sub> but in my opinion C<sub>iss</sub> has a much higher value in the diagram. Let's have a look at the characteristic curves in the data sheet (fig.17 and 18):

[image]

Am I getting something wrong?

- My last question is about the matrices given in the appendix of the paper. These were created by equations derived by the author from his circuit. Let's take matrix A (37) as an example, which (as I understood it) was derived from equations 4-7, 12 and 14. I don't understand how he gets to lines 2 and 4 because he seems to use some relationship between Coss, Ciss and Crss that I don't know yet. Does anyone have any idea how to get these rows of this matrix?

[image]

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Too broad - try asking a question that might be more easily answered by a single person. I really don't understand what you are saying about the capacitances either. The graphs look grainy but correct.

Comment: The lines 2 &4 are the Miller and 2nd order effects respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, most reputable manufacturers will give you models to their transistors, and Cree/Wolfspeed will give you LTSpice models. Modelling this piecewise in MatLab seems like a bigger pain than it's worth. That's just my two cents. On to your questions:

- There's no difference between \$I_D\$ and \$I_{DS}\$
- Transconductance is based on the derivative, not the average value. You can see that once the transistor is "on", the transconductance stays the same. While the (Vgs-Vt)/Id relationship may work for some devices, it does not work for most SiC MOSFETs, where the turn-on is much more gradual.

[image]

- The *data* for the ID/VGS curve appears to be for the 150°C Curve (see above). However, the paper does appear to be missing the piecewise equation that describes gm or Id relationship between (29) and (30) that is referenced in Fig. 5 as (30). If it's a journal article, those are frequently based on conference papers. Try looking for that.
- I see the Ciss capacitance on the graph as 1100pF. I have no idea why it's different between the written part of the datasheet and the graph. It could be a version issue, as that particular part is relatively old and may have had a datasheet revision. Ciss isn't that important, compared to the gate charge if you're looking at input parameters.
- Those look like matrix relationships for a simplified schematic (like the kind that a SPICE simulation does for you). It's based on the schematic that they have in Fig. 3d, and where it is in the simulation based on that. Look at their matrix definition immediately after Eq. (9) for what those may represent.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I know the models in Pspice. You're right, I think I'm getting too deeply into this. What I need is "only" a model/method with which I can calculate the switching losses depending on the temperature. Since some parameters like the transcoductance depend on the temperature, I thought that this model could help me. Even after a detailed research I couldn't figure out how to determine gfs using the data sheet of SiC-MOSFETs. Unfortunately this is missing in the paper, as you already mentioned.  I would be very grateful about sources. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Noah If you just need a number, you can digitize the plot with something like WebPlotDigitizer ( https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/ ). From there, when you have Figure 7 digitized, you will be able to take the piecewise derivative, which will be gfs.

Comment: Good answer with use of illustrations +1 so can you include gfs is always rated at max. @25’C which is why Vgs is not given in tables?

Comment: Gfs is always at rated a RdsOn and not for linear saturated or triode mode in these types used as switches

Comment: For those who are interested in a model to determine gfs, I can recommend the following paper: Analytical Switching Loss Modelling based on
Datasheet Parameters for MOSFETs in a
Half-Bridge.